# Challenge: How to do Title case with only Upper and Lower?

Tags: uppercase, lowercase, acumatica, title-case

Acumatica doesn't have a Title function... so I have a challenging question:

How can we create a Title function when there is only Upper and Lower function?

Below are the text functions currently available in Acumatica.

[image]

Comment: return UCase(Left(str, 1)) + LCase(Right(str,Len(str)-1)) ?

Comment: Can you define the function a little more precisely? The English language rule in a title is to capitalise individual words other than articles, conjunctions and prepositions. Which I'm going to assume isn't what you want because that implies a huge amount of complexity.

Comment: Wow thanks ergonaut! Please add this as an answer so I may select as answer.